# Dropdown filter in plotly, r - doesn't show "All"

Tags: r, button, filter, subset, plotly

I am trying to filter in Plotly by characters in a column but I can’t get it to show all data in that column as a button also.  I am also fitting a line to the data and would like to show all lines when the "All" button is pressed, and the lines be named accordingly.

Here is the sample:

```
library(plotly)    

qfitspec <- lm(Petal.Length ~ poly(Sepal.Length, 1), data = iris)

p <- iris %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = 'scatter', 
    x = ~Sepal.Length, 
    y = ~Petal.Length,
    text = ~Species,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    mode = 'markers', 
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter',
        target = ~Species,
        operation = '=',
        value = unique(iris$Species)[1]
      )
    ))%>%
  add_lines(y = ~fitted(qfitspec), name = "Species")%>%
  layout(
      updatemenus = list(
        list(
          type = 'dropdown',
          active = 0,
          buttons = list(
            list(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[1]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[1]),
            list(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[2]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[2]),
            list(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[3]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[3])
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

Ideally I would have:

- A 4th button called "All" that displayed all the data in the species column
- and show all the fitted lines in the subsets.

Thanks